# Laravel 5 Google/Bar Chart Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-visualization, bar-chart

I`m developing Bar chart using Laravel 5.4.but it gives an error.

[image]

Here is my Controller.

```
 public function division_details()
    {
    $chart = Charts::create('line', 'highcharts')
     ->setTitle('My Chart')
    ->setLabels(['One', 'Two', 'Three'])
    ->setDataset('Test 1', [1,2,3])
    ->setDataset('Test 2', [0,6,0])
    ->setDataset('Test 3', [3,4,1])
    ->setResponsive(false);
         return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails' ['chart' -> $chart] );
    }
```

here is my config/app/providers

```
ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
```

here is my config/app/aliases

```
'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
```

Can anyone suggest me the reason and the solution for getting this error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "set" part:

Controller:

```
public function division_details()
{
    $chart = Charts::multi('line', 'highcharts')
        ->title('My Chart')
        ->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three'])
        ->dataset('Test 1', [1,2,3])
        ->dataset('Test 2', [0,6,0])
        ->dataset('Test 3', [3,4,1])
        ->responsive(false);

    return view('registeredusers.divisiondetails' ['chart' => $chart] );
}
```

Somewhere in our view:

```
<head>
  ...
    {!! Charts::assets() !!}
  ...
</head>

<body>
   ...
    {!! $chart->render() !!}
   ...
```

Check the docs here: https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/tree/master/docs/4#create-charts

Comment: Now No errors sir,but nothing display only blank page.why is that?

Comment: Probably some syntax error. I've updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Yes. Show your controller and view.

Comment: I found the error it was not placing the {!!$chatrs->assest()!!}.anyway thank you very much.